# Is it ok to pass Ninject Web.Common UseNinjectMiddleware a lambda which returns a kernel instance?

Tags: c#, ninject, owin, ioc-container, ninject.web

Why does `UseNinjectMiddleware` take a lambda instead of a container instance?

Is it OK to do this?

```
var container = CreateKernel();
app.UseNinjectMiddleware(() => container);
```

instead of this:

```
app.UseNinjectMiddleware(() => CreateKernel);
```

My container instance in the first snippet is used to resolve dependencies in another part of my app. Does the Ninject Middleware need to be able to create it's own instances which it can modify, muck-around with and re-create at will? If not, I would like to avoid building the dependency tree more than once, hence why I'm wondering if it's OK for the lambda to just return the instance.

Comment: when I do this it, ninject does not kick in, maybe it goes out of scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things to note:

The [`OwinBootstrapper`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/blob/master/src/Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost/OwinBootstrapper.cs) component will load any defined `NinjectModule`'s after calling the passed in `Func<IKernel>` so you need to take care that you do not load anything twice. [see here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/blob/master/src/Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost/OwinBootstrapper.cs#L106)

The [`Bootstrapper`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/blob/master/src/Ninject.Web.Common/Bootstrapper.cs) component calls `Dispose` on `IKernel` so you will need to be sure you do not attempt to access the instance after a shutdown has been initiated. [see here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/blob/master/src/Ninject.Web.Common/Bootstrapper.cs#L74)

---

You can almost get to the underlying Kernel right after it has been created, maybe you would prefer to raise a PR to make it available?

Currently `OwinAppBuilderExtensions` defines

```
public const string NinjectOwinBootstrapperKey = "NinjectOwinBootstrapper";
```

which it uses to store the run-time instance of [`OwinBootstrapper`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/blob/master/src/Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost/OwinAppBuilderExtensions.cs#L52)

```
app.Properties.Add(NinjectOwinBootstrapperKey, bootstrapper);
```

`OwinBootstrapper` holds a private reference to the run-time instance of the [`Bootstrapper`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/blob/master/src/Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost/OwinBootstrapper.cs#L53) component and the `Bootstrapper` instance in turn exposes a reference to the run-time instance of `IKernel`

```
public IKernel Kernel
{
    get { return kernelInstance; }
}
```

So a little PR adding

```
public IKernel Kernel
{ 
    get
    {
        this.bootstrapper.Kernel;
    }
}
```

to `OwinBootstrapper` could make the underlying `IKernel` available to your code via `app.Properties` after the call to `app.UseNinjectMiddleware(() => container);`.